# Using Azure Service Bus Topics in Windows Phone 8

Tags: azure, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, azureservicebus, azure-servicebusrelay

I am working on a Windows Phone 8 app which is connected to Azure Service Bus Relay. Since i cant add Microsoft.ServiceBus.dll to the WP8 project, I had to go with BasicHttpBinding which works fine.

Now I want to use the service bus relay with topics in WP8. Is this even possible? I cant use NamespaceManager which is discussed here: http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/how-to-guides/service-bus-topics/ , because its not supported by WP8.

My question is simply, is this possible to do? And what approach should i choose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Zeezer,

> "Now I want to use the service bus relay with topics in WP8"

Not sure if you are conflating two separate issues...

We do not have an SDK for Service Bus Relay for the Windows Phone. However, if your service is using any of the **HttpRelayBinding*'s, you can use a regular HTTP client from the Windows Phone app to communicate with the Relay endpoint for your service. You will need to include the ACS token for authenticating to Service Bus Relay in a custom HTTP header called *ServiceBusAuthorization*.

Comment: Ok, so topics cant act as a relay too? Can you give me a code example of the custom HTTP header you are referring too, serched google which found 0 answers on "ServiceBusAuthorization".

Answer (score 3):

We do not have any libraries that target Windows Phone at this point but are working on producing these. You can make direct http calls to the REST APIs and send/receive messages etc. Samples for these are available:

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsazure/Brokered-Messaging-569cff88
https://github.com/WindowsAzure/azure-sdk-for-java/tree/master/microsoft-azure-api/src/main/java/com/microsoft/windowsazure/services/ServiceBus
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh780762.aspx